# Equality of proof-carrying dependent functions in Coq

Tags: coq

Suppose we have:

```
Require Import ZArith Program Omega.

Open Scope Z_scope.

Definition Z_to_nat (z : Z) (p : 0 <= z) : nat.
Proof.
  dependent destruction z.
    - exact (0%nat).
    - exact (Pos.to_nat p).
    - assert (Z.neg p < 0) by apply Zlt_neg_0.
      contradiction.
Qed.
```

Now I would like to formulate something like this:

`Lemma Z_to_nat_pred : forall x y p p', (Z_to_nat x p <= Z_to_nat y p')%nat <-> x <= y.`

This doesn't seem quite right to me, because in `x <= y`, I can have negative `x, y`, and then I won't have proofs about their positivity. All in all, the dependent `Z_to_nat` seems extremely difficult to use. How does one formulate that it suffices to show `x <= y` to conclude `(Z_to_nat x p <= Z_to_nat y p')%nat` and the other way around?

I've given it a bash to inspect the way I could formulate the proof (although I am fairly sure it can't be proven with this formulation).
I've tried:

```
Lemma Z_to_nat_pred : forall x y p p',
  (Z_to_nat x p <= Z_to_nat y p')%nat <-> x <= y.
Proof.
  intros.
  split; intros.
  - dependent destruction x;
    dependent destruction y; try easy; try omega.
```

Which leads me to the following goal:

```
p : positive
p0 : 0 <= Z.pos p
p' : 0 <= 0
H : (Z_to_nat (Z.pos p) p0 <= Z_to_nat 0 p')%nat
______________________________________(1/1)
Z.pos p <= 0
```

Could I here, for example, solve the goal by deriving contradiction from `H`, as `Z.pos p` cannot be `<= 0`? I can't really do much with the `Z_to_nat` definition.

Answer (score 2):

here are several remarks that are related to your question:

- In Coq when one defines functions using tactics and especially when we want to compute with, it is preferable to end the corresponding proof script with `Defined.`, not `Qed.` (the notion at stake is "transparent definition" vs. "opaque definition", cf. the Coq ref man)
- so if you replace `Qed` with `Defined`, the tactic `simpl in H.` will be applicable in your proof of `Z_to_nat_pred`
- **EDIT:** another tactic that would have been useful in your goal is `exfalso.`
- your function `Z_to_nat` is a *partial function* that takes a proof as argument. But in many practical cases, it is simpler to avoid dependent types, and just use a default value (making thus the function "total")
- this latter strategy is already that of the two functions below that are available in the the standard library (that you have already imported with `Require Import ZArith`). These two functions can be viewed as two ways to define your function `Z_to_nat` in a non-dependently-typed way:

  ```
  Print Z.abs_nat.

  Z.abs_nat = 
  fun z : Z => match z with
               | 0 => 0%nat
               | Z.pos p => Pos.to_nat p
               | Z.neg p => Pos.to_nat p
               end
       : Z -> nat

  Print Z.to_nat.

  Z.to_nat = 
  fun z : Z => match z with
               | 0 => 0%nat
               | Z.pos p => Pos.to_nat p
               | Z.neg _ => 0%nat
               end
       : Z -> nat
  ```
- Finally it appears that for each of these two functions, lemmas similar to yours are available in ZArith:

  ```
  SearchAbout Z.abs_nat Z.le iff.

  Zabs2Nat.inj_le: forall n m : Z, 0 <= n -> 0 <= m -> n <= m <-> (Z.abs_nat n <= Z.abs_nat m)%nat
  Zabs2Nat.inj_lt: forall n m : Z, 0 <= n -> 0 <= m -> n < m <-> (Z.abs_nat n < Z.abs_nat m)%nat

  SearchAbout Z.to_nat Z.le iff.

  Z2Nat.inj_iff: forall n m : Z, 0 <= n -> 0 <= m -> Z.to_nat n = Z.to_nat m <-> n = m
  Z2Nat.inj_le: forall n m : Z, 0 <= n -> 0 <= m -> n <= m <-> (Z.to_nat n <= Z.to_nat m)%nat
  Z2Nat.inj_lt: forall n m : Z, 0 <= n -> 0 <= m -> n < m <-> (Z.to_nat n < Z.to_nat m)%nat
  ```

Best regards